Meta API with User Token Returns Empty Response
Here are the steps I took to get access_token
// Init FB SDK
const loadSdk = () => {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        window.FB.init({
            appId: "218446344509498",
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: "v19.0",
        });
    };

    if (!document.getElementById("facebook-jssdk")) {
        const js = document.createElement("script");
        js.id = "facebook-jssdk";
        js.src = `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js`;
        document.body.appendChild(js);
    }
};

loadSdk();

Then I opened the popup that I need for whatsapp embedded sign up
window.FB.login((response) => {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        const code = response?.authResponse?.code;
        console.log(code)
    }
}, {
    config_id: <config-id>, // configuration ID goes here
    response_type: "code",
    override_default_response_type: true,
    scope: 'business_management, whatsapp_business_management, whatsapp_business_messaging',
})

When I code the code I retrieved my access_token on the server side using the following API
https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=<client-id>&client_secret=<client-secret&code=<code-i-previously-retrived>

This returns me an access token that seems to be working with Meta APIs
/me, //owned_whatsapp_business_accounts
But it returns empty arrays or objects.
When I do the same thing from Meta explorer (select permissions, generate token, copy that token and use, it works)
I have been trying to solve this since many days and not sure where I am doing the mistake.
I want to generate token with correct permissions (it looks like I am doing it because authentication popup also mentions the permissions I requested), and want to able to fetch information from it not empty array
